# Function computing the order of a pole

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I'm wondering if there's a function (mapping into the natural numbers) that computes the order of a pole of a meromorphic function ?

Put a little different, how does mathematical software finds this number? By looking at the exponents of the Lauent series? Or by approximation and then rounding?

At the end, what i would like to have, if possible, is a function similar to that computing the winding number at a point, where one does not have to "look" at the exponent to know the answer, if you see what I mean.

Thanks for your answers and thoughts.

Comment: You can use the argument principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle The way mathematicians use the word "function" there is tautologously a function that computes the order of a pole, which is just "the function that outputs the order of a pole." You can ask more specifically for an efficient algorithm or for a nice formula or something else if you want.

Comment: I think the Argument Principle is what I'm looking for (I'm not great with complex analysis, as you can see). Thanks!
Could you please post as an answer so I can mark as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) to compute the orders of zeroes and poles. This is done, for example, to verify the Riemann hypothesis computationally.